# Response 304: Not Modified has no content

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I upgraded my **Android Studio** from ver. **3.0.1** to **3.1**, and now, when i launch **gradle**, i have this error:

```
Response 304: Not Modified has no content!
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to activate this option in IDE settings[image]